# JCarousel not rendering in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, jcarousel

Got a big problem with JCarousel in Internet Explorer 8.

It works in all other browsers I've tested on. I'm hesitant to put a link to the site as I god nailed by someone here for trying to get hits - so I'll describe the problem.

In IE all the images are loading one underneath the other rather than in the CSS box.

Anyone had this problem and know how to solve it?

Comment: could you show code you are writing for carousel

Comment: <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-4d">
 <?php
 foreach ($flickr['photoset']['photo'] as $item) {
  echo '<li><img src="http://farm'.$item['farm'].'.staticflickr.com/'.$item['server'].'/'.$item['id'].'_'.$item['secret'].'_z.jpg" width="800" width="530" alt="'.$item['title'].'"></li>';
 }
 ?>
 </ul>

Comment: Despite your reservations, you need to add a link to your site if you want some help.

Comment: http://www.4dcreative.co.uk is the website. You can see in IE it's bust at the moment on the front page.

Comment: Your page is loading in quirk mode. Fix your DOCTYPE

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the DOCTYPE. In IE and FF the page loads in Quirks mode. Open FF, Tools and Page Info, it shows the details. You are missing the DTD in your DOCTYPE.